# How to read the OAuth request parameters with PHP?

Tags: php, oauth, header

I'm trying to connect an iPhone app to a PHP API using 2-legged OAuth as the Authentication mechanism. I'm using the PHP and Objective-C 2.0 libraries from http://code.google.com/p/oauth/ . The problem is that when I'm trying to issue a GET request with Objective-C, it doesn't include the OAuth parameters in the request URI, like the PHP library does when issuing an OAuth GET request:

`http://www.mysite.com/oauth/index.php?oauth_consumer_key=key&oauth_nonce=XXXXXXXX&oauth_signature=XXXXXXXXXXX%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1309863754&oauth_version=1.0`

Instead it puts the OAuth parameters in an Authorization header:

```
Authorization: OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="XXXXX", oauth_token="XXXX-XXXX",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="XXXXXXXX", 
oauth_timestamp="1309863855", oauth_nonce="XXXX-XXX-XX-XX-XXXXXXX", oauth_version="1.0"
```

I suppose that both ways are equally valid for the OAuth specs, right?

What's the best way I can read the Authorization header with PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suppose that both ways are equally valid for the OAuth specs, right?

Yes, right.

> What's the best way I can read the Authorization header with PHP?

Request headers in PHP are stored in the `$_SERVER` superglobal array, each header as an entry of it's own: `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` most probably in your case, just do

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

and look for the info. [Detailed information how PHP deals with the HTTP request](https://gist.github.com/1028251).

### Authorization header missing in PHP

Unfortunately the `Authorization` header is filtered by PHP(?), so it's not part of `$_SERVER`.

#### Workaround: apache_request_headers()

When using PHP as an Apache module, a workaround is to use the [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) function to retrieve all request headers.

#### Workaround: mod_rewrite

For F/CGI a workaround is to set the Authorization header with Mod_Rewrite into a environment variable that mimics PHP's scheme converting HTTP request headers:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

The mod_rewrite solution should work for PHP running with mod_php as well. Hat tip Jon Nylander.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION is nowhere to be found unfortunately... All the other headers are there, except this one.

Comment: Which webserver are you using and what's the SAPI type of your PHP?

Comment: The `Authorization` header is filtered by PHP, so it's not part of `$_SERVER`. On Apache you can use the [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) function to retrieve all request headers. For F/CGI I'm still looking

Comment: Apache and CGI/FastCGI respectively

Comment: To get the authorization header passed along to the environment when on cgi try the following Apache rewrite rule: https://gist.github.com/1069562

Comment: @Jon Nylander: Thanks for the hint, I had the same idea but was not able to test it so far. With a little change to `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]` it did it for me. Thanks! + Added it to the answer.

Comment: @Jon: [getallheaders available for FASTCGI in PHP](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/getallheaders-available-for-fastcgi-in-php/)

Comment: @hakre: great tip, I've never done CGI+PHP so never had reason to investigate.