# Problem with MAX_FILE_SIZE in PHP

Tags: php

I have a flex-based image upload form, and I've lost its source code. Now there appeared a problem with uploading big images (about 10MB), but with the same images an old html-based form works correctly. In my php-file there's

```
ini_set("post_max_size","64M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","64M");
```

Flex-based form returns file[error] = 2, that's MAX_FILE_SIZE error. It seems somewhere in flex there's an auto-generated field MAX_FILE_SIZE that it sends to server at the time it sends a file. I can't change this value in flex, so that's my question - is there a way to rewrite MAX_FILE_SIZE variable from php before php processes MAX_FILE_SIZE variable and generates error?

Comment: You might be able to change that in the HTTP server configuration on the fly, e.g. with .htaccess. Compare: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582264/how-to-read-the-oauth-request-parameters-with-php/6582740#6582740

Comment: Does that flex-based form accept any *FlashVars*?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change that values using ini_set that's probably the problem in the first place.
They can be set per directory so you can try to change their value in your .htaccess file

```
php_value    upload_max_filesize    64M
php_value    post_max_size    64M
```

Comment: Good point. Though, `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` as value of file[error] means that "*The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form*", so it's client-side problem as well.

Comment: certainly, but i just want to point out that point as i know this will the next breakpoint on the op process. But yes this doesn't help with the actual op problem